# Asp.net ViewModel for Create and Update Actions

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

In an ASP.NET MVC application do you have a different ViewModel for each controller action, or a shared one for all actions.

For example, if I have a Users controller with List and Create actions, should I have a UserViewModel, or should I have a CreateUserViewModel and ListUsersViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since listing all of the users and creating/ editing users are different things you probably will want 2 different views. However, you could create and share an Edit model/view between creating users and editing users.

Comment: Ok, another doubt, I've read one strategy is creating an independent viewmodel -> pattern 3 (http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx), in a list operation is this also relevant?

Answer (score 0):

If they are going to be pretty much the same properties, then it's fine to share. If not, then create 2. I usually end up sharing to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what information you need in your Views. If they use exactly the same information then sharing a ViewModel is fine. If one of them has all of the same information as another, plus more, then you can could have one inherit from the other, like this:

```
public class ListViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class CreateViewModel : ListViewModel
{
    public bool AcceptedTOA { get; set; }
}
```

With something like this, you could access all three values in your Create View but only `Username` and `Email` in your List View.

Edit: Adding more options...

Instead of inheriting, you can also put them inside of each other, e.g.

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
    public ListViewModel ListViewModel { get; set; }
    public bool AcceptedTOA { get; set; }
}
```

..and then in your View you would consume like...

```
@Model.ListViewModel.Username
```